# @Autowire in unit tests does not seem to work

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-mvc, mockito

I have a unit test setup using Mockito and Spring 4. My test looks like this:

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {
        MyTestConfig.class,
        SecurityConfig.class,
        OAuth2Config.class
})
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ControllerAccessTests {

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    private FilterChainProxy springSecurityFilterChain;

    @Mock
    private CreditCardPaymentService creditCardPaymentService;
    @InjectMocks
    private CreditCardRestController creditCardRestController;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
                .standaloneSetup(creditCardRestController)
                .apply(springSecurity(springSecurityFilterChain))
                .build();
        when(creditCardPaymentService.doPreAuthPayment(any())).thenReturn(null);
    }

    @Test
    //.... some unit tests
```

With a configuration file that looks like this:

```
@Configuration
public class MyTestConfig {

    @Bean
    public FilterChainProxy springSecurityFilterChain(){
        AntPathRequestMatcher matcher = new AntPathRequestMatcher("/**");
        DefaultSecurityFilterChain chain = new DefaultSecurityFilterChain(matcher);
        return new FilterChainProxy(chain);
    }

}
```

When I start the unit test `springSecurityFilterChain` is null, so it seems the configuration file `MyTestConfig` does not seem to get loaded. Any ideas?

Cheers
Tom

Comment: Use `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)` instead of `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to use mockito annotations and spring injection then:

**1)** Use `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)`

**2)** Create an init method:

```
@Before
public void init(){
 MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}
```

Comment: Ok, thanks for clarifying that. It makes sense I need the Spring runner to benefit from autowiring. However if I use that I get a `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext` exception when running the tests.

Comment: Maybe its because of an error inside the Spring configuration creation process itself.. does the full stack trace give any hints what might be the cause?

Comment: Ah thanks for the hint, yeah there are some more unsatisfied bean dependencies from spring security now. Gonna debug this. I will mark your response as solution since it solved the question and this is out of scope :) Thanks again for the explanation!